# Type error in python program

Tags: python

I always get a Type Error when I run the following python code (abc.py) as follows:

```
./abc.py activatelink alphabeta
Type Error: ['alphabeta']
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
from urllib2 import URLError
from urllib2 import HTTPError
import requests
import urllib
import json
import time
import os
import sys
import hashlib


def activate_user(link):
        print invoke_rest('GET', link)

def invoke_rest(request_type, rest_url, payload, headers):
        try:
                api_url = rest_url
                if request_type == 'GET':
                        r = requests.get(api_url)
                        to_ret = {'code':r.status_code, 'reply':r.text}
                        return to_ret
                elif request_type == 'POST':
                        r = requests.post(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
                        to_ret = {'code':r.status_code, 'reply':r.text}
                        return to_ret
                else:
                        return "Invalid request type ", request_type
        except Exception, e:
                return "Exception:", e, " in getting the API call"

def help():
    print ('Usage: %s { activate | help }', os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    actions = {'activatelink': activate_user, 'help': help}
    try:
        action = str(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        print "IndexError: ", sys.argv[1]
        action = 'help'
    args = sys.argv[2:]
    try:
        actions[action](*args)
    except (KeyError):
        print "Key Error:", args
        help()
    except (TypeError):
        print "Type Error:", args
        help()
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I added some other functions other than activatelink, which work fine, can anyone point out whats wrong in here?

Comment: Provide full exception stack trace, please.

Comment: Can you *remove* the exception handlers in your code so we can see the proper full exception with traceback rather than the `print` message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `invoke_rest()` function takes *four* arguments:

```
def invoke_rest(request_type, rest_url, payload, headers):
```

but you pass in just the two:

```
print invoke_rest('GET', link)
```

That raises a `TypeError` exception:

```
>>> def invoke_rest(request_type, rest_url, payload, headers):
...     pass
... 
>>> invoke_rest('GET', 'alphabeta')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invoke_rest() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Perhaps you wanted those two extra arguments (`payload` and `headers`) to be optional. If so, make them keyword arguments and set their default value to `None`:

```
def invoke_rest(request_type, rest_url, payload=None, headers=None):
```

which is fine by the `requests` library.